# Java SecretKey and replicating it's behaviour in C#

Tags: c#, java, encryption, sha1, 3des

I am trying to replicate the encryption logic found in a Java library in a C# application.

The Java contains two methods which I have managed to replicate in C#.  I get the same results in each program for any set of data.

```
createKey(byte data1[], MessageDigest md);
createIV(byte data2[], MessageDigest md);
```

The logic to generate the key and IV in Java is as follows:

```
public Cipher getCipher(byte[] password) {

    MessageDigest md = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-1");

    byte keyData[] = createKey(byte[] password, md);

     SecretKey secretKey = 
        SecretKeyFactory.getInstance("DESede").
        generateSecret(new DESedeKeySpec(keyData[]));

    IVSpec ivspec = createIV(secretKey.getEncoded(), md);

    Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("DESede/CBC/PKCS5Padding");
    cipher.init(1, secretKey, ivSpec, md);

    return cipher;
}
```

Let's say I have the follow:

```
Java Key HEX:       9c 3a 79 df ba 49 86 0 ed 58 1 d8 9b a7 94 0 bb 3e 8f 80 4d 67 0 0
```

When I build the secretKey and then call secretKey.getEncoded() I get:

```
Java Encoded Key: : 9d 3b 79 df ba 49 86 1 ec 58 1 d9 9b a7 94 1 ba 3e 8f 80 4c 67 1 1
```

Because I don't know what the SecretKey is doing internally I don't know how to replicate this in C#.

My current C# code looks like this:

```
    public static ICryptoTransform createCryptoTransform(String password)
    {

        ICryptoTransform ct = null;

        byte[] keyData = createKey(password);
        byte[] ivData = createInitialisationVector(keyData);

        printByteArray("keyData", keyData);
        printByteArray("ivData", ivData);

        TripleDESCryptoServiceProvider tdcsp = new TripleDESCryptoServiceProvider();

        tdcsp.Key = keyData; / This seems to be ignored by CreateEncryptor method below
        tdcsp.KeySize = 192;            
        tdcsp.IV = ivData; // This seems to be ignored by CreateEncryptor method below
        tdcsp.Mode = CipherMode.CBC;   
        tdcsp.Padding = PaddingMode.PKCS7; // PKCS5 and PKCS7 provide the same padding scheme

        ct = tdcsp.CreateEncryptor(keyData, ivData);

        return ct;

    }
```

As you can see, I'm using the ivData[] created from the unencoded key.

Everything works, that is I get the same encrypted result, if I pass the same IV data in when creating the encryptor but unfortunately I cannot modify how it generates it's IVSpec.

What is SecretKey doing internally and how do I replicate this in C#?

Comment: I'm guessing the difference is parity bits...

Comment: The issue seems to lie with parity bits:

If we look at the two keys:

    Java Key HEX:       9c 3a 79 df ba 49 86 0 ed 58 1 d8 9b a7 94 0 bb 3e 8f 80 4d 67 0 0
    Java Encoded Key: : 9d 3b 79 df ba 49 86 1 ec 58 1 d9 9b a7 94 1 ba 3e 8f 80 4c 67 1 1 

Values have either +1, 0 or -1 adjustments:

    9C = 10011100, this has an even number of 1s so we flip the last bit = +1
    79 = 01111001, this has an odd number of 1s so no change = -0
    ED = 11101101, this has an even number of 1s so we flip the last bit = -1

Comment: if you're still at it -- Can you post your final code.. I'm in the same boat with a legacy code (in Java) that I have to recreate in C#... and it's causing great pain. Please Help!!! (I cannot post publicly due to security, but maybe we could do a shared session ?!? Thanks in advance!!! Dan

Comment: At least for my problem above, it does look like the solution was to flip some bits based on the parity.  I can't post code at the moment but the basic algorithm was: A. count bits set to 1 B. if even flip least significant bit b = b & 0x01;  It's probably best to post your own question with a simple example of your problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

DES (and DESede) both derive 56 bits of key material from 64 bit input. The remaining 8 bits are used as parity check bits here. The [source code](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/com/sun/crypto/provider/DESedeKey.java#DESedeKey) shows you how Java handles this, you can apply the same in C#.

See also the section at the beginning of [FIPS 46-3](http://csrc.nist.gov/publications/fips/fips46-3/fips46-3.pdf).

Comment: It might be better to use AES instead of 3DES.  AES doesn't require parity bit setting for its keys and doesn't have the weak keys that DES has.

Comment: @rossum: Yes sure, I would prefer AES, too, if that is an option.

Comment: Thanks emboss, I'd figured out what to do but your answer really helps me to understand the background involved.  Unfortunately I have no choice on the key as both the current Java library and my new C# one have to talk to a C++ binary which cannot be changed.

Comment: @Karle: I thought so. Legacy stuff... causes nothing but trouble :)

Comment: @Karle  if you're still at it -- Can you post your final code.. I'm in the same boat with a legacy code (in Java) that I have to recreate in C#... and it's causing great pain. Please Help!!! (I cannot post publicly due to security, but maybe we could do a shared session ?!? Thanks in advance!!! Dan